# Jsoup add whitespace

Tags: tags, whitespace, jsoup

when parse with jsoup the following code:

```
<p>Long<a>word</a></p>
```

jsoup return:

```
<p>Long <a>word</a></p>
```

"Longword" is a single word. how to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your code?  When I parse that string, I do not get the extra space.

Comment: I can't replicate the error, but I solved it by putting prettyprint=false

Answer (score 0):

If I DID get your question right, and you want the text without the tags, and in the way they are shown in the browser, I'd use .text() if that's in a Element, or Elements variable. It should parse the "

Long word

", into simple "Longsword".

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("url").get();
Element link = doc.select("p");
System.out.println(link.text().replace(" ", ""));
```